# How to copy the Species name from a .fasta file header and add it to the same file name?

Tags: biopython

I have more than 5000 protein fasta files from different species.  The name of each files has a uniport ID (e.g, UP000000212_1234679.fasta). The first line of each file contains the Species name (e.g., >tr|K8E169|K8E169_CARML S4 domain protein YaaA OS=Carnobacterium maltaromaticum LMA28 GN=yaaA PE=4 SV=1. The species name always follows the OS=.... I would like to copy the species name from each file and add it to the beginning of each file name.  I am familiar with python and linux, but have not been able to figure out how to do it! Appreciate any help.

Thanks,
Ebi

Answer (score 1):

You have the "biopython" tag on here, so you can get the fasta header name from the SeqIO record using `record.description` .  Then you can use a regex to access the species name. Assuming the species name is always in the format you show here, i.e. it is delimited by "OS=" on one side and "GN=" on the other, something like

```
species_pattern = re.compile('OS=.*GN=')
```

Pull out the species name using e.g.

```
sp = species_pattern.findall (record.description)[0].replace('OS=','').replace('GN=','').strip()
```

and then save your file with that name. e.g.

```
SeqIO.write(record, '%s.fasta' % sp, "fasta")
```

There are of course many checks you would need to do along the line to make sure that you genuinely have the species name, that there is only one record per file, etc etc.